# Batch script - copy list of files with exclusions using a counter

Tags: batch-file, counter, xcopy

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong.

I want to copy a bunch of .log files from one dir to another but excluding the latest 2 (date modified) as they will be in use.

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
DIR /O-d /B %CurrentLogDir%\*.log > %TempRootDirectory%\journalsList.txt
SET /A Counter=0
FOR /F "delims=" %%a IN (%TempRootDirectory%\journalsList.txt) DO (
    SET /A Counter+=1
    IF !Counter! GTR 2 (XCOPY /Y /I %CurrentLogDir%\%%a %TempRootDirectory%\system\journals\current)
    SET LastJournalNumber=%%a
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Forget the counter, just skip the non needed lines

```
FOR /F "skip=2 delims=" ....
```